# How to override Map

Tags: scala

I'm reading 'Programming Scala' and one of the code samples is below :

Below code gives this error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - type mismatch; found : Unit required: B
    - type mismatch; found : Unit required: B

  abstract class CustomMap[A, B] extends Map[A, B] {

    def get(key: A) : Option[B] = {
      if (contains(key)){
        new Some(getValue(key))
      }
      else
         None
    }

    def getValue(key : A) = {

    }

  }
```

The error occurs at line :

```
new Some(getValue(key))
```

What form should the return type take ? I have tried returning int & String compiler does not accept it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's rarely necessary to sub-class the built-in collections, but if you really must then you should read the [collections documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html) first.

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup please see question edit

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to provide more information on what you're hoping to achieve. The compile error is easily fixed (for example, by defining `getValue` as `this(key)`, but that doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: Aaron Novstrup just trying to learn Scala . Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the error Tass pointed out, this looks like an artifact of the fact that you haven't implemented `getValue`. Try defining `getValue` as

```
def getValue(key: A): B = ???
```

until you're ready to provide an implementation.

I'm confused by your question, "What form should the return type take?", though. You mean the return type of `getValue`?  It should return a `B`.

Comment: Since 'B' is a generic type should I not be able to return a String ?

Comment: Because `B` is a generic type from the perspective of `CustomMap`, you cannot (in general) return a String since String may or may not conform to `B` for a specific instance of `CustomMap`. It would be a different matter if  you declared it as `CustomMap[A] extends Map[A, String]`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `Some(getValue(key))`.

Comment: removing the new keyword as per your answer results in same error.